# Responsive card-deck with same width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I'm setting up a web app, which call render a dynamic number of cards, which will display some information.

I managed to get them to use the same height, but have no idea on how to get them using the same width and height, even though if they are less cards in a row than the amount that would fit, they stretch and I don't want this behavior.

````
    <div class="card-deck">

    <div class="card mb-4">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Titel</h4>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Subtitle</h6>
        <p class="card-text">Text break </p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"><fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'sign-in-alt']"></fa-icon> Login</button>
      </div>

    </div>
    </div>
</div>```

Expected result: Every card uses the same width
Actual result: Cards in the last row (if they are less than the amount that would fit) stretch to the whole container
````

Comment: card-deck is not responsive, instead of that use bootstrap grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be achieved by using the

```
<div class="card mb-4 col-x">
```

where x in col-x, can range from 1 to 12 (***from bootstrap grid***),

it will generate the decks of the width specified.

Please refer to the link to code:

```
https://codepen.io/diveshpanwar/pen/WqvPNW
```

**Learn more about [Bootstrap grids](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/)**

Comment: thanks, bootstraps grids was the keyword I needed. Now I got it working

Comment: I am glad that it helped. Happy Coding.